# Debugging late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, azure, visual-studio, linq

When publishing a VB web app to Azure with Precompile During Publishing option selected and Allow Precompiled Site To Be Updateable de-selected the preview fails with "Late binding operations cannot be converted to an expression tree."
I'm willing to bet it's a linq query referencing an object property but I can't find it.
I feel like an idiot here. The project builds fine with no errors (Option Explicit, Option Strict are on; Option Infer is off in compile settings).
How do I debug for this error in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I feel rather idiotic here.
I was previewing the deployment and looking at the **VSDeploymentFailure**.txt file which has no details on the error.
Finally, I actually tried to publish the app and, when it failed, the output window showed me right where I had late binding in a few razor pages (turns out it wasn't a linq issue).